# UTF-8 can't decode by 0xf3 - SQL / Access / Python

Tags: python, sql, utf-8

I'm starting with python.
I'm trying to create a simple code to open a Access data base and retrieve some information through SQL queries.
Here is the draft of my code:

```
import csv, pyodbc

# set up some constants
MDB = 'C:/Samuel/Python/Caso79151.mdb'; DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'; PWD = 'pw'

# connect to db
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,MDB,PWD))
cur = con.cursor()
"""
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin-1')
con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='latin-1')
con.setencoding(encoding='latin-1')
"""
# run a query and get the results
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TB_PER;'
rows = cur.execute(SQL).fetchall()
cur.close()
con.close()
# you could change the mode from 'w' to 'a' (append) for any subsequent queries
with open('mytable.csv', 'wb') as fou:
csv_writer = csv.writer(fou) # default field-delimiter is ","
csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

As I execute the module, Python keeps showing the message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Samuel\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\Scripts\module1.py", line 18, in 
>       rows = cur.execute(SQL).fetchall()
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

As you can see, I've already tried to manage the error, trying a different encoding setup. I've had seen here a lot of similar problems that was fixed with this, but my code keeps not running, even with a different enconding.

When I try to run with the new enconding setup, the following message appers:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Samuel\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\Scripts\module1.py", line 9, in 
>       con.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin-1')
>   AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Connection' object has no attribute 'setdecoding'

Someone can give me a hand?

Thanks

Comment: Is this Python 3? According to [this document](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode), you should be using the method `setencoding` instead of `setdecoding`; it's probably going to be used for converting both ways.

Comment: Btw, once you've fixed this error, you'll run into trouble with the csv output: the `csv` module operates on files opened in text mode (`"w"` or `"wt"`), not binary.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.
The connection setup must be placed where? After the creation of the connection?
How can I use the code to do that, once you are warning me about the csv file? Actually the use of csv is for testing purpose. The "final" code will create a Excel file.

Comment: Of the three disabled lines concerning DB encoding, use the last one, right where it is now (outside the triple-quote string, of course). As for csv, use `"w"` or `"wt"` mode instead of `"wb"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that out!

Comment: Well, after I've looked the table inside the data base I think I've figured out the source of the problem.
The first column header is PER_Código. So, 0xf3 is the ASCII code for the "ó". [Source](https://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/243/en).
The question is how can I declare the correct enconding/decoding parameters in order to pyodbc can read the data without problems?

Comment: There is no ASCII code that is larger than `7F`. The byte value `F3` is the Latin-1 encoding of "ó".

Comment: Any chance that the source the problem could by the pyodbc version? I'm using portable python and a figured out that it is been shutdown. Is there a modern distribution/version of python that doesn't need instalation?

Comment: I have no idea. And it seems like you are driving away from your original question now.

Comment: Not exactly, since the problem could be the pyodbc version. I can keep the current version of python, but maybe I'll need do upgrade the pyodbc version. The version within python portable is '3.0.2'. As far as saw, the current version is 4.0.21. Looking up through internet I've found some recommendations to upgrade to solve some encoding/decoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my suspicious were right. I've just upgraded to Anaconda with a newer version of pyodbc and the code ran without errors.
Thank you anyway as your comments made me thought in different perspectives to solve the issue.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I see this error in postgres "to_sql" UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte, having configured the database in utf8, passing a pandas dataframe by average following the instruction `df.to_sql("table", connection, schema="schema", index=False, if_exists="replace")`, actually had accents in the letter search on the web for the error and find nothing, but well Debugging tells me that this error description is poorly defined as a response to the library, my problem was that the database did not have the table schema created.